# Length of input string in assembly language

Tags: string, assembly, x86, dos

I want to do two things:
1) Take a string from user
2) Find the length of that string

I tried the following code:

```
.model small    
.stack 100h
.data
    MAXLEN DB 100
    ACT_LEN DB 0                ;Actual length of the string  
    ACT_DATA DB 100 DUP('$')    ;String will be stored in ACT_DATA
    MSG1 DB 10,13,'ENTER STRING : $'
.CODE
START:
    MOV AX,@data
    MOV DS,AX
    ;Normal printing 
    LEA DX,MSG1
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    ;Cant understand code from here!
    LEA DX,ACT_DATA
    MOV AH,0AH
    MOV DX,OFFSET MAXLEN
    INT 21H

    LEA SI,ACT_DATA
    MOV CL,ACT_LEN

    ;AND THEH SOME OPERATIONS

END START
```

But I am confused how the length is stored in `CL` register, i.e. how the `ACT_LEN` value is incremented? And what actually does `mov AH,0A` has relation with length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Int 21/AH=0Ah](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm)

```
Format of DOS input buffer:

Offset  Size    Description     (Table 01344)
00h    BYTE    maximum characters buffer can hold (MAXLEN)
01h    BYTE    (call) number of chars from last input which may be recalled (ACT_LEN)
(ret) number of characters actually read, excluding CR
02h  N BYTEs   actual characters read, including the final carriage return (ACT_DATA)
```

The buffered input interrupt will fill in these values.

```
LEA DX,ACT_DATA
MOV AH,0AH
MOV DX,OFFSET MAXLEN
INT 21H
```

You do not need `LEA DX,ACT_DATA`

`mov AH,0A` is the number of the interrupt to call.  [Ralph Brown has a big list](http://ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) of interrupts with descriptions and what goes in/comes out.

Comment: How does ACT_LEN value is changed.Sorry i didnt get you!Is it all done by instruction MOV AH,0Ah by offset 01h??

Comment: @Gunner : How does this work? Where and when is the string's length saved?